# How to convert gyro data to extrinsic/global/world euler xyz angles?

Tags: acceleration

I know that I can get gyro angles by integration, but that are not the angles I need.

I need the same angles that I calculate from the accelerometer (extrinsic euler xyz angles) to apply properly a complementary filter.

Background: I am building a flight controller for a quadcopter.

Comment: Search on here, this has been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of the answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441900/how-use-raw-gryoscope-data-s-for-calculating-3d-rotation

**I represent the rotation as a quaternion and then convert it to any angle I want.**

But I still don't understand why there is no problem in interpreting the gyro angles as Euler angles and converting them into a (delta) quaternion. The gyro angles don't have any order in which they were moved so the end position should always differ depending on the order the gyro was moved in the respective angle.